# BFS traversal of directed graph from a given node

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

My understanding of basic *breadth-first search* traversal for a graph is:

```
BFS        
    Start from any node. 
    Add it to queue. 
    Add it to visited array.

    While queue is not empty:
        Remove head from queue; 
        Print node.

        add all unvisited direct subchilds to que; 
        mark them as visited
```

However, if we have to traverse a *directed* graph from a given node and not all nodes are accessible from the given node (directly or indirectly), how do we use BFS for traversing the graph of this situation?

Can you please explain in this graph as well:

```
a=> b => d => e => d  
a=> c => d
```

Here if the starting node is `b` , we never print `a` and `c`.

Am I missing something in the algorithm?

I used  `HashMap<String, ArrayList> adj = new HashMap();` to create the adjacency list to store graph.

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. If the nodes are unreachable, the search won't find them.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if we have to traverse a DIRECTED graph from a given node and not all nodes are accessible from the given node [directly or indirectly] how do we use BFS for the same.

A search algorithm traverses a graph. If you have edges that cannot be traversed and thus nodes that cannot be reached, the search will simply not find them.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your understanding, *except* for the "Start from any node" part -- a BFS traversal must begin from the root node. So in your example, you would *have* to begin with node a, otherwise, as you have said, you will never visit it.

Comment: The same goes for depth-first search, too.

Comment: Graphs don't necessarily have root nodes. The question is clearly about graphs.

Comment: However, the question, from what I can see, is about DAGs and DAGs do have one or more root nodes (and if it has more than one root node, any graph-search algorithm will miss some nodes, unless all root nodes are added to the initial set).

Comment: Thanks for your comments .
I am sure this issue would be faced in number of real problems.

Is there any algorithm to find a root node in DAGs. I want to traverse the complete graph from a root, similar to "testing bipartiteness" problem.

Thanks