# Directed Graph BFS without all nodes reachable

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I'm doing a breadth-first search on a digraph. I'm lost at nodes c and f, and I'm not sure if and how they should be in the BF-tree or if you only go as far as reachable from the source node and don't start at another node in order to get all the vertices.

Here's what I'm getting so far. As you can see, letters mark the nodes. Distance and predecessor are marked by d and pi:

[image: BFS digraph]

This was helpful [BFS traversal of directed graph from a given node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582576/bfs-traversal-of-directed-graph-from-a-given-node) but I'm not familiar with graphs enough to understand how that applies to this situation.  From what I'm getting from that question, it seems like in this case I would not include c and f at all.

In fact, it seems like I have the maximal number of nodes included already, just because I started at i.  I think that the d=4 at the g node (also at k but that doesn't even connect to any other nodes), this is the greatest distance and max-depth possible in BFS in this graph.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You should remember the idea behind bfs....its gives you all the nodes reachable from starting node with increasing distance...use it anyway you want

Comment: @bapu -- ok so, it seems like there's only have 1 source per search. so then c and f would be infinite distance since the source is already started at node i. somewhat confusing because the algorithm's for loop seems to go over every vertex (but not sure if that's every G.v or just the v reachable because there can be only 1 source).

Comment: Yes you have to start your BFS again from another unvisited node if you want to visit every node of the graph ...depends on what you want to do if you are planning to find shortest distance between 2 nodes you will start BFS from one node and stop when you find the other node..but if you are looking for a particular node you have to do BFS from each unvisited node till you find it

Comment: BFS is a really general graph algorithm you can do a couple of things with it by slightly changing it or starting it at specific nodes. What do you want to achieve with your BFS?

Comment: @stackuser did you ever get the solution? I am stuck at a similar problem